# Docker-Compose yaml Editor for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, docker-compose, yaml

Is there a plugin for Eclipse that provides a sophisticated docker-compose.yml file editor?

Sophisticated means for instance proper schema checks and syntax completions/suggestions.

Unfortunately, the official Eclipse Docker tooling does not provide such a specialized editor.

Comment: I was looking for the same thing, only have found tooling for DockerFile support

Comment: There's a ticket in the bug tracker https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=561119